# Python - dataframe group by and save to a file each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Data is in Pandas Dataframe.
When do a `groupby` on a specific column - this is what I get:

```
df.groupby('REPORT_DATE').count()
REPORT_DATE     
2016-07-01  2079
2016-07-05  2079
2016-07-06  2079
2016-07-07  2079
```

How to automatically save each of these 2079 values in a separate file?
So in above case it would be:

```
2016-07-01.csv
2016-07-05.csv
2016-07-06.csv
2016-07-07.csv
```

With 2079 items in each.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090355/writing-multiple-files-from-one-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing multiple files from one pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090355/writing-multiple-files-from-one-pandas-dataframe)